# Как из скрипта .js перемещаться по вкладкам хром?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Запускаю .js-скрипты в браузере хром (через плагин UI.vision RPA, но можно и напрямую). Не могу найти вариант переключения по открытым вкладкам браузера из скрипта.

Пробовал через crome.tab API управлять вкладками, но, как я понял, хром не даёт разрешение скрипту пользоваться этими настройками. Вкладки не обязательно открыты `window.open()` - хотя и управлять открытым скриптом тоже не получается :)

Какие возможны варианты решения данной проблемы? Спасибо!

P.S. Ранее, например, в старом FF, прекрасно работал переход по вкладкам, таким не хитрым способом:

```
var Tabs = {
    _browser: function () {         
        var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"] 
             .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);      
        return wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").gBrowser;
    }(),

    go: function (tabIndex) {
        this._browser.selectedTab = this._browser.tabContainer.childNodes[tabIndex - 1];    
    }
};
```

и вызывался `Tabs.go(1)` - первая вкладка слева и т.д.

Comment: Может всё-таки через селениум?

Comment: К сожалению в javascript коде много данных, массивов и т.д. Прерывание кода, выход их executeScript в UI или Silenium команды не желательно. Или вы имели ввиду, что в Silenium из executeScript мы можем вызвать команду Селениума? А в UI нет таких средств?

Comment: напрямую надо  написать правильный манифест на свое расширение, которое загрузит яваскрипт

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду. А не могли бы показать кодом, либо примером. Буду вам очень Благодарен! Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно не хватает разрешений на расширении которое запускает скрипт https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/

https://habr.com/ru/articles/718644/

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую разобраться, где настраивается manifest для плагина хром, который запускает js

Comment: Посмотрел манифес плагина UI.vision RPA - платформа  (из которого запускаю js скрипты через команду executeScript). В ней права на "tabs" даны. По идее chrome.tabs должен позволить скрипту Js ходить по вкладкам, но этого не происходит. Значения в manifest.json "permissions": [ "bookmarks", "clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite", "cookies", "debugger", "downloads", "notifications", "storage", "tabs", "proxy", "nativeMessaging", "contextMenus" ],